# Moving windows programmatically on MacOS in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to move a window programmatically on my desktop. For this I've tried:

```
let options = CGWindowListOption(arrayLiteral: .excludeDesktopElements, .optionOnScreenOnly)
    let windowsListInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(options, CGWindowID(0))
    let windowsList = windowsListInfo as NSArray? as? [[String: AnyObject]]
    let visibleWindows = windowsList?.filter{ $0["kCGWindowLayer"] as! Int == 0 }

    for window in visibleWindows! {
        let windowTitle = window["kCGWindowOwnerName"] as! String
        let windowNumber = window["kCGWindowNumber"] as! Int32

        if windowNumber == 124 { // Safari
            let nsWindow = NSApp.window(withWindowNumber: Int(windowNumber))
            nsWindow?.cascadeTopLeft(from: NSPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0))
            nsWindow?.setFrameTopLeftPoint(NSPoint(x: 100.0, y: 100.0))
        }
    }
}
```

but when I'm trying to get `NSWindow` by using `windowNumber`:

```
NSApp.window(withWindowNumber: Int(windowNumber))
```

I get `nil`.

So my question is, how can I move any window programmatically by knowing its windowNumber?
I've even tried to bring that window to front and

```
let pid = window["kCGWindowOwnerPID"] as? Int32 {
let app = NSRunningApplication(processIdentifier: pid)
app?.activate(options: .activateIgnoringOtherApps)
```

doing this but nothing helped me.
Could someone help me to find out the way how I can move the Safari window(for example) programmatically?

Comment: One way of doing it is use of AppleScript.  That's how I did it several years ago in Objective-C.  If you can do it with NSApp, then that sounds better.

Comment: With NSApp the window must be owned from your app. 
"window(withWindowNumber:) may return nil for window numbers found using windowNumbers(options:) if there is no corresponding window object owned by your app—for example, the menu bar"
I would try with Apple script or accessibility API.

Answer (score 6):

This should get the trick done:

```
let owner = entry[kCGWindowOwnerName as String] as! String
var bounds = entry[kCGWindowBounds as String] as? [String: Int]
let pid = entry[kCGWindowOwnerPID as String] as? Int32

if owner == "Safari"
{
    let appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid!);
    var value: AnyObject?
    let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appRef, kAXWindowsAttribute as CFString, &value)

    if let windowList = value as? [AXUIElement] {
        print ("windowList #\(windowList)")
        if let window = windowList.first
        {
            var position : CFTypeRef
            var size : CFTypeRef
            var  newPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            var newSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 800)

            position = AXValueCreate(AXValueType(rawValue: kAXValueCGPointType)!,&newPoint)!;
            AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(windowList.first!, kAXPositionAttribute as CFString, position);

            size = AXValueCreate(AXValueType(rawValue: kAXValueCGSizeType)!,&newSize)!;
            AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(windowList.first!, kAXSizeAttribute as CFString, size);
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I found this code in another discussion which I can't find at the moment, sorry about that

Oh and you need this code to request the accessibility access:

```
let options: NSDictionary = [kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as String : true]
let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options)

if !accessEnabled {
    print("Access Not Enabled")
}
```

Hope this helps, even if it's been a year and five days since you posted this question :)

Comment: well, as someone thinking of writing a program to do this today, I thank you, even if the original poster didn't :)